# Python script running on Spyder but not if I open the .py file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to use Keras in Python to create a network that identifies handwritten digits from the MNIST library for a class project.

So in programming class last semmester we were using IDLE but I had problems installing Tensorflow on stock python so I downloaded Anaconda and downloaded Keras and `tensorflow-gpu` with the `conda` command,

Within Spyder everything works fine but when I open the `.py` file I'm getting a bunch of errors and the program crashes.

I confirmed that the file is opened with `python.exe` from the Anaconda installation path. I'm attaching my code and the errors im getting.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

def small_CNN():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape = (1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model


def big_CNN():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(30, (5,5), input_shape = (1, 28, 28), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(classes, activation = 'softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model

numpy.random.seed(7)

(d_train, c_train), (d_test, c_test) = mnist.load_data()

d_train = d_train.reshape(d_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32') / 255
d_test = d_test.reshape(d_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32') / 255

c_train = np_utils.to_categorical(c_train)
c_test = np_utils.to_categorical(c_test)
classes = c_test.shape[1]

model = big_CNN()
model.fit(d_train, c_train, validation_data = (d_test, c_test), epochs = 5, batch_size = 200, verbose = 1)
scores2 = model.evaluate(d_test, c_test, verbose=0)
print(str(scores2[1]*100)+"%")
```

ERRORS:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.643244: W c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.646784: W c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.650180: W c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.653900: W c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.657146: W c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.660899: W c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.664397: W c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.667624: W c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2018-05-07 17:14:42.961063: I c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 960
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.291
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 2.00GiB
Free memory: 1.12GiB
2018-05-07 17:14:42.965514: I c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0
2018-05-07 17:14:42.967183: I c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y
2018-05-07 17:14:42.969153: I c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2018-05-07 17:14:43.781059: I c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/5
2018-05-07 17:14:45.912647: E c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:359] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2018-05-07 17:14:45.915318: E c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:366] error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
2018-05-07 17:14:45.925473: E c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:326] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
2018-05-07 17:14:45.928009: F c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:659] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
```

Comment: Please copy / paste errors instead of image - ho, and pls, format errors as code block

Comment: The program crashes really fast but i will try

Comment: Can't you keep the window open and just copy / paste output? (I don't know nothing about Window :/)

Comment: Yes i did the output is above

Comment: When you say *"Within Spyder everything works fine"*, do you mean you can run your keras code inside spyder and it reaches the end?

Comment: Yes it reaches the end and produces good results

Comment: And where are you trying to open the code that produces an error?

Comment: I'm opening the .py file using python.exe from the anaconda installation folder as i mentioned before

Comment: Did you create any environment with anaconda?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170552/discussion-between-frank-f-and-daniel-moller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some help by Daniel Möller I was able to fix the problem by adding these lines at the begining of my code (after i import everything):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

Funny thing is on spyder training took about 3-5 seconds per epoch and it now takes 20-25 AND when I open the .py file i still get all the warnings but it runs correctly until the end training at 3-5 seconds per epoch. The problem if i understand correctly from this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6698#issuecomment-297179317) provided by Daniel, had to do with GPU memmory allocation.